# Valgrind equivalent for OpenCL

Tags: opencl, gpu, valgrind, gpgpu

To check memory access violations on the CPU, there's Valgrind/memcheck; for CUDA code on the GPU, there's [CUDA memcheck](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-memcheck).  Is there an equivalent to these tools for OpenCL?

Comment: Probably not, valgrind emulates linux, and CUDA memcheck probably emulates,  or works at the driver level. Unless someone wrote a custom OpenCL driver, I dont see how it would be possible. What kind of memory stuff are you doing?

Comment: Nothing particularly fancy, I just want to rule out GPU memory access violations.  I'm getting a memory access violation within the CPU code when I call `clFinish()`.

Comment: Have you tried running the same code on the CPU and then using valgrind ? I am not entirely sure it will help, but if there are any access violations in the OpenCL code, it should happen on the CPU as well and should be caught by valgrind.

Comment: @PavanYalamanchili I've tried, but I can't get the installation to work on my Linux virtual machine.  I could try one of the Valgrind equivalents for Windows, though.  Are you sure it will work?

Comment: @1'' Are you using OpenCL + GPU on windows or in Linux VM ?

Comment: @PavanYalamanchili In Windows.

Comment: GPU can not generate SEG_FAULTs and pass them to host code, as far as I know, that never happened to me. The only error I had once is to corrupt my screen by using OpenCL. The typical problems of SEG_FAULTs in OCL calls are because some arguments of thouse functions are not valid. (The dynamic library with the CL calls has been unloaded, null pointers, pointers already deleted, etc.)

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/KhronosGroup/webcl-validator? It takes your OpenCL kernel source and instruments it with bounds checking code. OOB reads/writes are currently discarded, but you could modify the instrumented kernel (or the tool itself) to make it report the access violation.

Comment: @TomiAarnio Thanks! Put that into an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is now an OpenCL device simulator called [Oclgrind](https://github.com/jrprice/Oclgrind/wiki) that works in a similar manner to Valgrind to provide a 'memcheck' feature (among other things).

It's open-source, and there are binary builds for various platform available. Like Valgrind it's not fast, but using it is very straightforward:

```
$ oclgrind ./myapp

Invalid write of size 4 at global memory address 0x3000000000010
    Kernel: write_out_of_bounds
    Entity: Global(4,0,0) Local(4,0,0) Group(0,0,0)
     store i32 %tmp15, i32 addrspace(1)* %tmp19, align 4, !dbg !24
    At line 4 of input.cl:
        c[i] = a[i] + b[i]
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at http://github.com/KhronosGroup/webcl-validator? It takes your OpenCL kernel source and instruments it with bounds checking code. OOB reads/writes are currently discarded, but you could modify the instrumented kernel (or the tool itself) to make it report the access violation.